# gradle fails with Problems reading data from Binary store error

Tags: android, gradle

I have a Gradle file that runs the tests. It does not build anything. All it has is a unzip task that extracts all jars in a Gradle configuration into a particular directory and then runs the task of type Test. This test task points the testClasses directory to the location where the previous copy task has extracted the configuration into.

My build fails with the error message:

> Problems reading data from Binary store

When I run 'gradle dependencies' it does not show any error/warning
When I run the copy task individually, it runs very well fine.
Only when I run everything it fails with error :

```
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':testConfig'.$
   > Problems reading data from Binary store in /tmp/gradle8793563212642185736.bin (exist: false)$
```

I see the file `/tmp/gradle8793563212642185736.bin` does not exist. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: I suddenly started seeing this behavior this morning; the build was working fine Friday. I'm using Gradle 3.2.

Comment: Can you perhaps provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Can you please provide the gradle file in question

Comment: It was with gradle 2.x; I do not have a reproducible environment now. Not seeing this issue anymore with gradle 3.x

Answer (score 6):

Turns out it was just a network problem for me. Gradle just needed to connect to the internet.

Answer (score 6):

I solved upgrading following packages to last version (06/02/2021), so:
project app-level `build.gradle` file:

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2
```

to

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.2
```

Project-level build.gradle file:

```
com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3
```

to

```
com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case the writing problem was there was no enough storage to build the app so I needed to restart my Mac and it finished building successfully.

*I know am too late but it might help someone in the future so*

Comment: Yes, indeed your answer helped me. I was facing the error "Problems writing to Binary store in C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\gradle3087369407772225066.bin (exist: true)". After reading your answer, I found out my storage is only 1.4GB left(total 500GB). After I removed some useless files, the available storage is 6.7 GB. Rerun the gradlew command, it's successful. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

In my case setting `org.gradle.parallel=false` flag fixes the issue, but it's not a solution for my project, flag increase CI build time from ~15min to ~45min.

Comment: Can you specify where do you add that flag? Which file?

Comment: `gradle.properties` but not sure if it make any change. I tried many things, and this is random from my perspective. Sometimes it's not possible to work, sometimes disappears for few days.

Answer (score 3):

I was working with version 5.x earlier and then I upgraded to 6.0.1 and it resolved the issue.
this is how you can upgrade

```
cd android
./gradlew clean
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 6.0.1
./gradlew -v   # to download the new version
cd ..
flutter clean
flutter run   # might take 15 - 20mins for the first time
```

Answer (score 2):

It happened with Flutter development in my case. Apparently, it is not an actual issue and there is no magic fix. Cleaning build file with "Flutter clean" and restarting the command line executer window solved the issue.

Comment: but did it solve at once? and what do you mean by restarting the command line executer window solved the issue ??

Comment: yep, it solved the issue totally. I meant the error is misleading, the problem stems from something else. It maybe solved with just cleaning build files or restarting the app/platform you use for it - eg. Command Prompt, Linux command line or Git. Of course, there maybe some other tricks as mentioned by others as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are mainly a few steps to solve this problem.

1. Go to gradle.properties and set `org.gradle.parallel=false` and sync. Make sure your sync gradle offline option is off
2. Start the build with this option. If it's a big project setting `org.gradle.parallel=false` will take a long time.
3. Cancel the build repeat the steps setting `org.gradle.parallel=true`.

Also do not turn on offline build

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked in my flutter project. I solved it by making these changes:

1. In android level build.gradle file, replace `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'` with `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'` (basically upgrade the version from 3.5.4 to 4.0.1)
2. In gradle-wrapper.properties file, replace `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip` with `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip` (upgrade from 5.6.2 to 6.1.1)

and if you have added `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'` to android level build.gradle file, replace that too with `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'` (upgrade from 4.3.3 to 4.3.5)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up here after publishing an artifact to `mavenLocal()`.

I tried a lot but in the end what helped me was:

- Upgrading gradle from 6.3 to 6.9

```
 ./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 6.9
```

*Hope this saves me half an hour next time this occurs.*

Answer (score 0):

Start by upgrading Gradle to the latest version.

Binary store issues reported to [GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=%22binary+store%22+repo%3Agradle%2Fgradle&type=Issues) are often fixed right away, especially if they include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

If upgrading didn't work, it can be useful to run the task again with [Performance options](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_performance) disabled:

- `--no-parallel`
- `--no-configure-on-demand`

Next please find an [existing issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues) or open a new one so it can be fixed in future versions. These things are all helpful:

- Minimal, Reproducible Example
- [Build Scan](https://guides.gradle.org/creating-build-scans/)
- Smallest change that introduced the problem (e.g. worked on 5.5, but not 5.6)

Comment: The problem is that is completely random. Build failed 3 times on CI server and then 3 hours later, it ran just fine with no changes. The same error couldn't be reproduced locally at the same time. The issue is present in 6.4.1 and all the way back to at least 3.2, as mentioned above. It seems to be a threading issue where Gradle deletes it's own temp file before it should. That seems to be why random changes "fix" the issue. It would be helpful if the error reported the dependency in question but that might not help since the entire temp file is not present.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ***Cedric's*** hint, stopping gradle offline mode and make it online, fixed the issue for me